# awk/nawk alternative on SunOs and Linux

Tags: awk, posix, portability

I have a script that basically checks the Java version on the box it's running on and does whatever based on the version number.

My problem is that I want to use the same command on both SunOs and Linux boxes.

The closest I have come to this is...

**SunOs:**

> java -version 2>&1 | nawk -F '"' '/version/ {print $2}'

This gives the expected output of `1.7.0_09`

and...

**Linux:**

> java -version 2>&1 | awk -F '"' '/version/ {print $2}'

This gives the expected output of `1.8.0_05`

I want to know if I can get the same result, with the same command on the different OS's

Comment: can you simply `alias` one of the commands or create a simbolic link, or should this be universal? If so, you could check for the existence of either program and specify the respective command in an `if` loop.

Comment: just get OS type and use an `if`, easier than bashing head over something trivial

Comment: @gwillie I thought of that, but I wanted a more elegant way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a portable way :

```
java -version 2>&1 | PATH=`getconf PATH` awk -F '"' '/version/ {print $2}'
```

Unlike the usual suggestions that try to guess the correct location depending on the Unix implementation, it uses the `getconf PATH` command that returns the path to POSIX compliant commands.