# Pass variables from SHELL to AWK

Tags: awk, scripting, solaris, variable

I want to write a one liner on Solaris 11 to check the space in each of the zpools of my systems.
The output would look like this...

```
myzone1 rpool 83%
myzone2 rpool 49%
```

All the posts I've read say to use the -v switch to pass a shell variable to awk.

Everytime I try I get an error.

This code works.  I get the pool and the percentage used.

```
for i in `zoneadm list -icv|grep running|awk '{print $2}'`; do
    zlogin $i zpool list -H|awk '{print $1" "$5}';
done
```

I want to add the zonename to this report output.
This code does not work for me!

```
for i in `zoneadm list -icv|grep running|awk '{print $2}'`; do
    zlogin $i zpool list -H|awk -v i="$i" '{print i" "$1" "$5}';
done
```

Can you help me find where I am making a mistake?

Comment: Related: [POSIX awk on Solaris 11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360359/posix-awk-on-solaris-11)

Comment: `awk -v myvar="$shellvar" 'END {print myvar}'`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this comment:

Related: [POSIX awk on Solaris 11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360359/posix-awk-on-solaris-11) – [Mark Plotnick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399994/pass-variables-from-shell-to-awk#comment714368_399994)

I rewrote the code to:

```
for i in `zoneadm list -icv|grep running|awk '{print $2}'`; do zlogin $i zpool list -H|/usr/bin/nawk -v i="$i" '{print i" "$1" "$5}';done
```

This works the way I want it to report.

Comment: Don't forget to vote on the questions and answers you found helpful!

Comment: How do I vote for Mark Plotnick's answer?  It is in a comment.

Comment: Vote for the question/answer that he linked to, of course.